# PHP foreach Two arrays, find a value in one, use a different field in the other (add to array)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am perfectly okay with being told this is a duplicate.

I have an array that I need to lookup a value in itself for reference to link one entry to another. That's the backstory.

Source array:
Array is:

> [0] => { [0] => "111", [1] => "description1", [2] => "222" }
>   [1] => { [0] => "222", [1] => "description2", [2] => "" }

Result desired:
Array:

> [0] => { [0] => "111", [1] => "description", [2] => "222", [3] => "description2" }
>   [1] => { [0] => "222", [1] => "description2", [2] => "" }

(where description2 is found by matching "222" and returning the field. I don't really care if nothing matches.)

I think I can do as much as lookup 222 if I specify it. I'm trying to invoke the power of posting to get my head around the linking back to the desired output.

**How do I look up a value (from a needle array) in a haystack array and return a different [key=>value pair] from that array?**
(yes this is so much easier in SQL. I think I want to know how to do a JOIN).

Comment: You mention a needle and haystack array, suggesting 2 seperate arrays, yet your example shows only a single source array. Please give a more detailed example of what you want to do

Comment: @user574632 Thank you for your comment. For the purposes of explanation, duplicate the source array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
$haystack=$array1;
foreach ($array1 as $record) {
    $needle = $record[2];
    foreach ($haystack as $stack) {
       if ($stack[0] == $needle) {
           $record[] = $stack[1];
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = [[111,"description1",222]];
$array2 = [[222,"description2"]];
$arrayAux = [];
foreach($array1 as $arr1){
    if(is_numeric($arr1)){
        $arrayAux[] = $arr1;
    }
}
foreach($array2 as $key => $arr2){
    if(in_array($arr2, $arrayAux)){
        $array1[] = $array2[$key++];
    }
}
print_r($array1); //$array1 = [[111,"description1",222,"description2"]];
```

Or you can use array_join: http://php.net/array_merge

```
$array1 = array_merge($array1,$array2); //Output: [[111,"description1",222,"description2"]];
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. It likely suffices. To clarify, $arrray1 = [[111,"description1",222],[222,"description2"]] and $array2=$array1.

Comment: Put this code inside another foreach, replace the $array/$array2 to the foreach key/value.